# End of string expected error when trying to post comment in Weblog

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, weblog

I'm trying to solve an issue with posting comments for a blog that uses the Weblog Sitecore module. From what I can tell, if the blog entry url contains dashes (i.e. http://[domain.org]/blog/2016/december/test-2-entry), then I get the "End of string expected at line [#]" error. If the blog entry url does NOT contain dashes, then the comment form works fine.

```
<replace mode="on" find="-" replaceWith="_"/>
```

Also tried to replace the dash with an empty space. Neither solution has worked as I still get the error.

Is there some other setting in the Web.config I can alter to escape the dashes in the urls? I have read that enclosing dashed url text with the # symbol works, but I'd like to be able to do that automatically instead of having the user go back and rename all their blog entries.

Here is a screenshot of the error for reference:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not experience the Weblog module but for the issue you are facing, you should escape the dash with `#`. Please see the following code snippet:

```
public string EscapePath(string path)
{
    string[] joints = Regex.Split(path, "/");
    string output = string.Empty;
    for (int index = 0; index < joints.Length; index++)
    {
        string joint = joints[index];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(joint))
            output += string.Format("#{0}#", joint);

        if (index != joints.Length - 1)
            output += "/";
    }

    return output;
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/issues/52

More information about escaping dash in queries can be found [here](http://www.ipointsystems.com/blog/2013/october/sitecore-query-error)

**UPDATE**

You should call this method before posting the comment for it to escape the dashes. You may also download the dll from [here](http://www.singlestoneconsulting.com/%7E/media/files/SitecoreModulesWeblog.zip) and use it in your solution

Comment: This looks like a good solution but I have no idea where this function should be placed....

Comment: As i already provided in the answer, i haven't use the Weblog module. Maybe you can ask on the github page provided in the answer. But i think there must be a pipeline that you can override in the module to add the method

Comment: If i am not mistaken, check the xml node weblogCreateComment in the weblog.config. I think it is there that you should place the method. I think it should be the first to run